# 2 jQuery-скрипта не работают на одной странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Первый скрипт, который подключен внизу страницы, не работает (скрипт поиска товаров на сайте):

```js
window.onload = () => {
    let input = document.querySelector('#iteminput');
    input.oninput = function(){
        let value = this.value.trim();
        let list = document.querySelectorAll('.ul li');
        if (value != '') {
            list.forEach(elem => {
                if (elem.innerText.search(value) == -1) {
                    elem.classList.add('hide');
                }
            });
        } else {
            list.forEach(elem => {
                elem.classList.remove('hide');
            });
        }
        console.log(this.value);
    };
};
```

Второй скрипт, который подключен внизу страницы, работает (скрипт прелоадера при загрузке страницы):

```js
document.body.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        var preloader = document.getElementById('page-preloader');
        if (!preloader.classList.contains('done')) 
        {
            preloader.classList.add('done');
        }
    }, 1000);
};
```

`div` для второго скрипта:

```html
<div id="page-preloader" class="preloader">
        <img src="icons/uTemp_intro.png" class="loader">
        <img src="icons/from.png" class="loader-from">
</div>
```

`div` для первого скрипта:

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col justify-content-center">
        <input type="text" id="iteminput" class="searchinput" style="margin-top: -20px; max-width: 500px;" placeholder="Поиск одежды">
        </div> 
</div>
```

Подключение скриптов в низу страницы:

```html
<script src="search.js"></script>
<script src="preloader.js"></script>
```

Я в JS не профессионал, и данные скрипты были сделаны по шаблонам. Буду рад любым советам.

Comment: В представленном коде нет Jquery........ Чтобы найти место затыка - используйте отладку и консоль разработчика (см. в дубликате)